# Deleting messages in telegram bot sometimes doesn't work

Tags: c#, nuget, telegram-bot

I've written a telegram bot which deletes messages that are sent to a super-group between certain times. I'm using **Telegram.Bot** version 12.0.0-beta-04.

```
    private async void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
       if(DateTime.Now.Hour<=6 and DateTime.Now.Minute<=30)
       {
           _bot.DeleteMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, e.Message.MessageId);
       }
    }
```

The problem is that if for example at 2 AM, I send one message it doesn't do anything but if I send two or more messages with little delay, It works and deletes all of them. Any ideas why this happens?

**Edit:**
My Bad. For example, If Hour is 3 and minute is 45, that wouldn't work. I fixed the code and It's working perfectly.

```
   if ((DateTime.Now.Hour < 6) ||
    (DateTime.Now.Hour == 6 && DateTime.Now.Minute <= 30))
   {
      _bot.DeleteMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, e.Message.MessageId);
   }
```

Comment: Can you quantity "little delay"?

Comment: I mean 30 seconds.

Comment: why do you use `async` if u don't `await` ?

Comment: I haven't written the complete code but I used `await`.

Comment: why don't you  use limiting the privileges of users in some period of times? it is possible in the new version of telegram bot api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a better solution to prevent new messages in the group. change your bot and try to limit users' privileges by "restrictChatMember" and then give their privileges back by "promoteChatMember".

Comment: You're right but currently It's not available in Nuget. [Telegram.Bot NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telegram.Bot/12.0.0-beta-04)

Comment: Note that you have the whole structure ready! Adding 2 new functions to the library may need few minutes. Simply adding above functions in the below file and some minor changes can do the job :-) https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot/blob/master/src/Telegram.Bot/TelegramBotClient.cs